# Reading space separated numbers in cobol

Tags: cobol

I am trying to solve a geometry problem using COBOL. The question requires me to read space separated integers(6 of them which stand for x and y coordinates of 3 points). Now the problem comes when I try to read them using ACCEPT. The numbers aren't read using space as a delimiter. I am using this

```
ACCEPT AX
ACCEPT AY
ACCEPT BX
ACCEPT BY1
ACCEPT X
ACCEPT Y
DISPLAY AX
DISPLAY AY
```

when I give an input of 
1 2 2 1 2 2

AX contains 000012212
and AY contains 000000000.

All variables are of length 9.

The DATA-DIVISION

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 TP       PIC X(126).
   01 AX       PIC S9(20).
   01 AY       PIC S9(20).
   01 BX       PIC S9(20).
   01 BY1      PIC S9(20).
   01 X        PIC S9(20).
   01 Y        PIC S9(20).
   01 T        PIC S9(5).
   01 ABC      PIC S9(36).
   01 ABD      PIC S9(36).
   01 CDA      PIC S9(36).
   01 CDB      PIC S9(36).
```

This is the part where I accept the strings of coordinates.

```
  ACCEPT TP.
  DISPLAY TP
  UNSTRING TP
  DELIMITED BY ALL SPACE
  INTO AX
       AY
       BX
       BY1
       X
       Y
```

Comment: If the maximum number of digits is 9, define the data at (9). For now, don't remove the S, as they can't be signed, which we'll have to deal with now we've seen negatives in your data.

Comment: By "don't" I meant just "remove". So for the co-ordinates, define `PIC 9(9)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ACCEPT all the input into 1 variable, and then break it down with a PERFORM UNTIL construction to get all the numbers right.

Comment: But I don't know the length of the numbers, because they can be arbitrary

Comment: I understood that the numbers can be of any length (up to 9), this is why I suggested to do the job with PERFORM UNTIL statements.
Try and read first char, add it to your number, read next one, if it's a number then multiply your number by 10 and add the current one. You do this until you hit a SPACE. You will have a second PERFORM UNTIL that will do the 6 numbers.

Comment: That seems like a good idea! But how do you read character by character in COBOL?

Comment: You don't "read" character-by-character. After your ACCEPT you can process the data character-by-character. See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089663/cobol-code-to-replace-characters-by-html-entities, for instance (in the question).

Comment: Indeed, you read the whole data in one accept, then REDEFINE the variable used with an OCCURS and then you can go through each char.

Comment: Hello. I suggest you mark one of the answers as accepted in this case, so we know that this question is solved. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use ACCEPT, use UNSTRING to separate the data into fields and then validate those:

```
01  INPUT-COORDS PIC X(12).

01  XY-COORDS.
    05  X-COORD-1 PIC 9.
    05  Y-COORD-1 PIC 9.
    05  X-COORD-2 PIC 9.
    05  Y-COORD-2 PIC 9.
    05  X-COORD-3 PIC 9.
    05  Y-COORD-3 PIC 9.

ACCEPT INPUT-COORDS
MOVE SPACE TO XY-COORDS
UNSTRING INPUT-COORDS
  DELIMITED BY ALL SPACE
  INTO X-COORD-1
       Y-COORD-1
       X-COORD-2
       Y-COORD-2
       X-COORD-3
       Y-COORD-3
  ON OVERFLOW
     do something meaningful
END-UNSTRING
```

Then validate the data thus extracted.

```
IF X-COORD-1 NOT NUMERIC, etc
```

I didn't check your input data. With only one-digit co-ordinates being valid, you can also consider this:

```
01  XY-COORDS.
    05  X-COORD-1 PIC 9.
    05  FILLER    PIC X.
        88  XYC-SEP1-OK VALUE SPACE.  
    05  Y-COORD-1 PIC 9.
    05  FILLER    PIC X.
        88  XYC-SEP2-OK VALUE SPACE.  
    05  X-COORD-2 PIC 9.
    05  FILLER    PIC X.
        88  XYC-SEP3-OK VALUE SPACE.  
    05  Y-COORD-2 PIC 9.
    05  FILLER    PIC X.
        88  XYC-SEP4-OK VALUE SPACE.  
    05  X-COORD-3 PIC 9.
    05  FILLER    PIC X.
        88  XYC-SEP5-OK VALUE SPACE.  
    05  Y-COORD-3 PIC 9.

ACCEPT XY-COORDS
```

Then do the same validation as above, plus check that the separators are each space (using the 88s).

Comment: Not working, only integer-1 gets the correct value. Rest of them get 0s. I declared some-descriptive name as a Z PIC X(200)

Comment: @billyjayan Check over the update, see if it helps. If not, you'll need to add the code which is not working to your question, so that we can see why. Data-definitions, Procedure code, and input data.

Comment: @billyjayan Now seeing your comment on the other answer, I can see they are not all one digit. Can you update your sample so that it reflects what you may receive, please?

Comment: @BillWoodger I think he did -- "all variables are of length 9" so I guess he means PIC 9(9).

Comment: Hey! I tried using unstring but if there is more than one trailing zero in the input at the end, it is not accepting the second zero. For eg. If this is the input->
181156 217672 -28318 -335670 -17922 831300 , Then the string(which I later unstring) after accepting it is 
181156 217672 -28318 -335670 -17922 83130(the last zero is omitted). I've declared the string as PIC X(200)

Comment: Can you paste the code and definitions you are using into your question please?

Comment: I tried a bit more, and found that no matter what the last digit was in the above mentioned input, it doesn't appear in the output