# COBOL code to replace characters by html entities

Tags: html, cobol

I want to replace the characters '<' and '>' by `&lt;` and `&gt;` with COBOL. I was wondering about INSPECT statement, but it looks like this statement just can be used to translate one char by another. My intention is to replace all html characters by their html entities.

Can anyone figure out some way to do it? Maybe looping over the string and testing each char is the only way?

GnuCOBOL or IBM COBOL examples are welcome.

My best code is something like it: (http://ideone.com/MKiAc6)

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HTMLSECURE.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
77 INPTXT PIC X(50).
77 OUTTXT PIC X(500).
77 I PIC 9(4) COMP VALUE 1.
77 P PIC 9(4) COMP VALUE 1.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MOVE 1 TO P
    MOVE '<SCRIPT> TEST TEST </SCRIPT>' TO INPTXT

    PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1
            UNTIL I EQUAL LENGTH OF INPTXT

        EVALUATE INPTXT(I:1)
            WHEN '<'
                MOVE "&lt;" TO OUTTXT(P:4)
                ADD 4 TO P
            WHEN '>'
                MOVE "&gt;" TO OUTTXT(P:4)
                ADD 4 TO P
            WHEN OTHER
                MOVE INPTXT(I:1) TO OUTTXT(P:1)
                ADD 1 TO P
        END-EVALUATE
    END-PERFORM

    DISPLAY OUTTXT

    STOP RUN
    .
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want to do. At the moment, it would seem you don't want to do anything (change > to > and < to <). Can you show some representative sample input and expected output?

Comment: I worked out by looking in edit how to show what you want, I included backticks aroung the &lt; and co to stop them being processed literally. Can now see what you are after.

Comment: Which part of the suggested variety of solutions did you Accept? :-)

Comment: OK, it's still not clear what you are going to go with. Part of the point of the questions and answers is to help future searches with similar questions. Someone finding this won't know exactly what helped you.

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right.

Comment: I think that would be generally portable. If you have working code and you want to know if it can be improved, that's a question for the Code Review site on StackExchange, I think. If you click on StackExchange on the top left you'll find a list of sites, in alphabetical order, Code Review among them. You'll be the second COBOL question, I think :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COBOL is a language of fixed-length fields. So no, `INSPECT` is not going to be able to do what you want.

If you need this for an IBM Mainframe, your SORT product (assuming sufficiently up-to-date) can do this using `FINDREP`.

If you look at the XML processing possibilities in Enterprise COBOL, you will see that they do exactly what you want (I'd guess). GnuCOBOL can also readily interface with lots of other things. If you are writing GnuCOBOL for running on a non-Mainframe, I'd suggest you ask on the GnuCOBOL part of SourceForge.

Otherwise, yes, it would come down to looping through the data. Once you clarify what you want a bit more, you may get examples of that if you still need them.

Comment: SORT wouldn't help because it should be online. The last accomplishment is a code that compiles under any COBOL compiler.

Answer (score 1):

GnuCOBOL (yes, another name branding change) has an intrinsic function extension, FUNCTION SUBSTITUTE.

```
move function substitute(inptxt, ">", "&gt;", "<", "&lt;") to where-ever-including-inptxt
```

Takes a subject string, and pairs of patterns and replacements.  (This is not regex patterns, straight up text matching).  See http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/#function-substitute for some more details.  The patterns and replacements can all be different lengths.

As intrinsic functions return anonymous COBOL fields, the result of the function can be used to overwrite the subject field, without worry of sliding overlap or other "change while reading" problems.

Comment: Nice. Pity about the portability, but still nice.